# Ignore fields from being passed on in Json Object

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a POJO called `User` which is also being used for inserting documents in MongoDb.

```
@Data
@Document(collection = Constants.COLLECTION_USERS)
public class User {

    public ObjectId _id;

    public String userID;

    public String email;

    public String name;

    public String sex;

    public String dob;

    public String photo;
    //have more variables

}
```

I have a simple application where a user registers by giving in a subset of data listed in the `User` class. The signature of the register method in my controller is as follows.

```
public GenericResponse registerUser(@RequestBody User userRegistrationRequest)
```

It can be noticed that I am using the same POJO for the registration request. Until now everything is fine. I can persist the data user object just fine.

This registration API is just used to persist a small set of a user's data. There would be other information as well in the MongoDb document, which would be accessed/persisted from some other APIs.

Suppose a user has registered with the basic information and also has persisted other information via APIs other than the registration one.

How would I make an API which can just get me some selective data from the `User` document again using the same User Pojo? If I call the repository to give data for a specific userID, it will give me the whole document mapped to the User class. I don't want my API to give all the information stored in the document.

**One approach** is to make another POJO with the details I want, and map the information selectively using a `Converter`. But, I want to avoid this approach, as I want to use the same class.

**Second approach**: Modify the Mongo query to return data selectively as given in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/). But here I would have to specify all the fields I want in the result set. This would again be a length query.

Is there a better way to filter out data from the object?

Comment: One of the core principles of design is the single responsibility principle. You're actively trying to violate it as much as you can by wanting to use the same class to represent: 1. a persistent User information in the database, 2. the data sent as JSON input when registering, 3. data retrieved and returned as output from yet another API endpoint. Having separate classes to represent different things is a *good* thing. You shouldn't try to use the same class for everything.

Comment: But wouldn't the other classes contain only a subset of attributes in the given User class. I see all those classes as redundant code. PS: I am a noob

Comment: @JBNizet So, are you saying that  I should rather use different classes and use Converters for mapping data ?

Comment: By avoiding to write trivial code, you're creating bigger readability and maintenance problems. Here are some of them: one could populate fields of the class that shouldn't be by simply guessing their name and submitting it in the JSON. You or a colleague might break one API by adding/removing a field and not realizing the same class is used in a completely unrelated use case. Reading the class doesn't make it possible to know what is actually expected from the client or sent to the client. etc. etc. Yes, use different classes for different purposes, and use a converter or an ad-hoc query.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for explaining the design principles. I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I make an API which can just get me some selective data from the User document again using the same User Pojo?

How would I go off-road with a car I would like to take me girl to the restaurant at the evening? **I would not** - if I would have the same car for everything I would look stupid next to the restaurant, coming out in a suite or I would stuck in a swamp.

The biggest Java advantage is [object creation time](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149563/should-we-avoid-object-creation-in-java) - you should not be afraid of it. Just create another model for registration, another as DTO for saving data, another for front-end presentation etc

**Never** mix responsibility of objects. You will finish with something like

```
@Entity
class ThePileOfShit {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @my.audit.framework.Id
    private String anotherId;

    @JsonIgnore
    // just a front-end flag ignore
    private boolean flag;

    @Column
    // not a field but getter because of any-weird-issue-you-want-to-put-here
    public String getWeirdStuff() { ... }

    // Useless converters
    public ModelA getAsModelA() { ... }

    public ModelB getAsModelB() { ... }

    // etc
    // etc
}
```

Four frameworks, five technologies - nobody knows what's going on.

If you are afraid of converting stuff use [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) or another tool but keep your POJOs as simple as possible

Comment: Solve one problem, get another one - redundant declarations in this case, as you invariably have the same fields in multiple classes, and now you also have to keep your mappers up-to-date. Plus the converters aren't "useless", you simply moved them to the mapper (which tends to be less flexible than you'd want it so you'll have your hand-written converters back, in the long run, with the added complication that it's only in some very specific cases which then tend to become surprising for maintainers).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gson's](https://github.com/google/gson) `@Expose` annotation only on the fields you want to return in the API.

To serialize the data, use:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
String json = gson.toJson(userData);
```